# How do I get all data from this api into a UILabels in a UITableView?

Tags: swift, codable

Currently I am using the Tracker Network API for Apex Legends and have hit a problem. I am unable to get all the data back from the api. As you can see below I can call...

```
self.legendTitle = [json.data.children[0].metadata.legendName]
```

However, this is only giving me the index of 1. I wanted to know how I could get all these indexes into an array(legendTitle). Currently, I am only receiving one index as the above code shows. Also, leaving out the '[0]' will throw errors.

Here is the code I am using to sort through the APIs JSON.

```
import Foundation

struct Store: Codable {
    let data: DataClass

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
    }
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let id: String
    let type: String
    let children: [Child]
    let metadata: DataMetadata
    let stats: [Stat]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case type = "type"
        case children = "children"
        case metadata = "metadata"
        case stats = "stats"
    }
}

struct Child: Codable {
    let id: String
    let type: String
    let metadata: ChildMetadata
    let stats: [Stat]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case type = "type"
        case metadata = "metadata"
        case stats = "stats"
    }
}

struct ChildMetadata: Codable {
    let legendName: String
    let icon: String
    let bgimage: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case legendName = "legend_name"
        case icon = "icon"
        case bgimage = "bgimage"
    }
}

struct Stat: Codable {
    let metadata: StatMetadata
    let value: Int
    let percentile: Double?
    let rank: Int?
    let displayValue: String
    let displayRank: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case metadata = "metadata"
        case value = "value"
        case percentile = "percentile"
        case rank = "rank"
        case displayValue = "displayValue"
        case displayRank = "displayRank"
    }
}

struct StatMetadata: Codable {
    let key: String
    let name: String
    let categoryKey: StatsCategoryOrder
    let categoryName: CategoryName
    let isReversed: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case key = "key"
        case name = "name"
        case categoryKey = "categoryKey"
        case categoryName = "categoryName"
        case isReversed = "isReversed"
    }
}

enum StatsCategoryOrder: String, Codable {
    case combat = "combat"
    case game = "game"
    case weapons = "weapons"
}

enum CategoryName: String, Codable {
    case combat = "Combat"
    case game = "Game"
    case weapons = "Weapons"
}

struct DataMetadata: Codable {
    let statsCategoryOrder: [StatsCategoryOrder]
    let platformID: Int
    let platformUserHandle: String
    let accountID: String
    let cacheExpireDate: String
    let level: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case statsCategoryOrder = "statsCategoryOrder"
        case platformID = "platformId"
        case platformUserHandle = "platformUserHandle"
        case accountID = "accountId"
        case cacheExpireDate = "cacheExpireDate"
        case level = "level"
    }
}
```

Then here is my code that I am using to get the data and then put certain data sets into arrays which I would then display in a UITableView.

```
let formattedName = usernameEntry.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

    let PlayerStatURL = URL(string: "https://public-api.tracker.gg/apex/v1/standard/profile/\(selectedPlatform)/\(formattedName)")

    if let unwrappedURL = PlayerStatURL {
        var request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedURL)
        request.addValue("My-API-KEY", forHTTPHeaderField: "TRN-Api-Key")
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            // you should put in error handling code, too
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Store.self, from: data) as Store

                    // print(json.data)


                    //account level
                    print("Level: \(json.data.metadata.level)")


                    self.legendTitle = [json.data.children[0].metadata.legendName]

                    self.title1 = [json.data.children[0].stats[0].metadata.name]
                    self.data1 = [json.data.children[0].stats[0].value]



                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)

                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() ) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.viewDidLoad()
                self.statusOfLoad.stopAnimating()
                self.statusOfLoad.isHidden = true
                }
            }

        }
        dataTask.resume()


    }


}
```

As you can see I also have title1 and data1, which I will also put into arrays for the tableView. 
I just have not been able to figure out how to get all available 'legendNames' into 'legendTitle'. (along with the other two)

For API Key: https://apex.tracker.gg/site-api

Comment: Just use `map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just have not been able to figure out how to get all available 'legendNames' into 'legendTitle'

Change

```
self.legendTitle = [json.data.children[0].metadata.legendName]
```

to

```
self.legendTitle = json.data.children.map{$0.metadata.legendName}
```

Comment: Quick question. For this code I get an error because not every index has a stat name at 1.  'print(json.data.children.map{$0.stats[1].metadata.name})'

Comment: That is new information and would be a new question, I expect.

Comment: Alright will do, but thanks for the above info. It really helped.